# Time taken to send iOS GameKit message

Tags: ios, gamekit, core-bluetooth

So I am trying to write a simple app that will connect to another iPhone and send messages over bluetooth, and it seems like the best way to do this is using the GameKit. If I am wrong, please point me in the right direction now before you read this whole question, haha.

### The two requirements are:

1. iPhone to iPhone, same application (easy)
2. I can get the time it took to send the unreliable message (not easy)

I am going to assume this is not possible over GameKit based on the (little) research I have done, and I have not yet found a good guide to the CoreBluetooth framework. Once again, if you could point me in the right direction that would be appreciated.

TL;DR: Is there a way using GameKit to get how long it took the small unreliable message to be sent? If not, can I do this with CoreBluetooth?

-Jake

Comment: what cant you do with gamekit?  Time the latency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feels like a strange question, you want to know, how long it took to send the message between the two phones?

The way to this is to set up a ping between client and server, the server will ping the client, then the client immediately sends the response back to the server, and the server divides the total time by 2.

Comment: I guess this makes sense, maybe I am just over thinking it. I am trying to compare two iPhones internal clocks so I guess I could have one device initiate, the other sends a response with its system time and then use the time it took to get back divided by two to get the time of the response and then calculate the difference between the two. Thanks.

Comment: sure thing.  Getting the clocks to sync is almost impossible, even with them getting the time from the cell network.  Latency is usually a very small number.

Comment: I dont need them to sync, its more of an experiment to see the difference in them.